# making python interpreter open in same window

Tags: emacs, buffer, python-mode

Maybe I'm being irrational but I really really hate it when a command opens a new window in emacs.  I'm using emacs on Ubuntu which came with python-mode and when I start an interpreter with C-c ! it pops up in a new window.

What I want is for emacs to switch to a new buffer in the same window.  So far I've tried adding *Jython*(I set the interpreter to jython) to same-window-buffer-names and even going into python-mode.el and changing switch-to-buffer-other-window calls to switch-to-buffer(which I since changed back).  So far I've gotten no change.

I have emacs 23.1.1 and python-mode 5.1.0

Edit: The actual name of the jython buffer is bracketed by asterisks and I don't know how to let stackoverflow know that they aren't styling information.

Comment: Can you be specific about which Emacs version (and maybe with python-mode version) you are using?  I don't even have C-c ! in my 22.3.1 GNU version.

Comment: Sorry to be gone so long.  I have 23.1.1 and python-mode is 5.1.0

Answer (score 1):

current python-mode.el from

http://launchpad.net/python-mode

comes with a customizable variable

py-shell-switch-buffers-on-execute-p

"When non-nil switch to the new Python shell. "

related:  py-split-windows-on-execute-p 
  "When non-nil split windows."

Beside commands ending with switch/noswitch
allow to ignore the customized or default setting

See menu PyExec

Answer (score 0):

I use python-mode 5.2.0.

I went into python-mode.el and changed the switch-to-buffer-other-window to switch-to-buffer.
I evaluated it and now the interpreter opens up in the same window (regardless of the number of other windows I have).

Did you evaluate the function when you changed the above line?

Btw, opening the interpreter in another window is a feature, not a bug, IMHO. We want to be able to see the interpreter when we evaluate a region of code using C-c | or the buffer using C-c C-c.